# How to place a full width background image?

Tags: jquery, image, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working with bootstrap I managed to place a full width background image.
The question is what resolution should the image be created in?

Should it be 1600x1200 and let bootstrap framework adjust it? but what about higher resolutions?

The result I strive to have is like on this page:
http://www.indochino.com/product/white-casual-shirt

The image is like a banner. If I understand correctly they created 1600x1200 images.

Comment: Then take a look at [their images](http://d3dgk6r8ca2pzn.cloudfront.net/images/productimages/s/1600x1200/x1376046533.2116883757.background.original.jpg.pagespeed.ic.f522CAjhaU.jpg) as an example of how to deal with this problem. Usually the image gets re-sized in big screens losing a bit o quality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a larger image and then use CSS3's background-size: cover. It completely fills the div/body with the background image you provided. In other words, it automatically resizes the background image to fit the element no matter the dimension.

```
#div {
 background: url("someimage.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}
```

or

```
#div {
 background: url("someimage.jpg");
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yet, not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @Alvaro i did mention CSS3.  There are workarounds but i am currently using mobile.